# react-router-redux syncHistoryWithStore crash / passing state with react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

Basically the problem is I couldn't pass the state using react-redux with react-router. In my component I have a code like this:

```
    export default connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
        reduxState: state,
        ownProps
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        onSyncState: (state) => {
            dispatch({type: 'SYNCHRONIZE_STORE', payload: state});
        }
    })
)(Home);
```

but when I try to console log the props I see that I have reduxState: undefined. dispatch works fine.
So now I try to use react-router-redux to synchronize them.

In my index.js file I have a code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home/Home.component';
import Edit from './Edit/Edit.component';
import './index.css';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, Redirect, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import categoriesService from './Services/Categories.service'

const initialState = {
    tasks: categoriesService.getTasks(),
    categories: categoriesService.getCategories(),
    currentCategory: 1,
    filterString: '',
    showDone: 'show'
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === 'SYNCHRONIZE_STORE') {
        console.log(action.payload);
        console.log(state);
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools());
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Redirect from="/" to="/home/1/show/" />
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                <Route path="/home/:category/:showDone(/:filter)" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/edit/:category/:task" component={Edit} />
            </Route>
            <Redirect from="*" to="/home/1/show/" />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

categoriesService is a mocked synchronous service that just returns mocked data arrays.
When I try to do this with syncHistoryWithStore I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'routing' of undefined
    at defaultSelectLocationState (sync.js:14)
    at syncHistoryWithStore (sync.js:37)
    at eval (index.js:62)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1372)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at eval (multi_main:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:589)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at bundle.js:579
```

So, I'm out of ideas. Hope you can help to fix react-router-redux, or to pass the state somehow else. :)

Comment: please provide the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, guys, this is just dumbness of mine. :) I'd forgotten to return state in the end of my reducer. :) And, I'd forgotten to combine reducers with routing to use it with syncHistoryWithStore. And it looks like I wasn't really know how this should even work.

So here's the working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home/Home.component';
import Edit from './Edit/Edit.component';
import './index.css';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, Redirect, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import categoriesService from './Services/Categories.service'

const initialState = {
    tasks: categoriesService.getTasks(),
    categories: categoriesService.getCategories(),
    currentCategory: 1,
    filterString: '',
    showDone: 'show'
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (action.type === 'SYNCHRONIZE_STORE') {
        console.log(action);
        console.log(...state);
    }
    return state;
}

let combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    routing: routerReducer,
    reducer
});

const store = createStore(combinedReducers, composeWithDevTools());
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Redirect from="/" to="/home/1/show/" />
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                <Route path="/home/:category/:showDone(/:filter)" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/edit/:category/:task" component={Edit} />
            </Route>
            <Redirect from="*" to="/home/1/show/" />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: ohhh sorry i forgot to write that in my answer, anyways happy coding :)

Comment: @Codesingh no worries. :) Thank you!

Comment: Welcome brother :)

Answer (score 2):

try using : `...state` inside `console.log()`